# How to parse data into an array or dictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, cocoa-bindings, gcdasyncsocket

I have an app that makes multiple connections to different servers at the same time. I want to record each connection in an array so I can display them in a tableview and use them in a different section of my app. This is what I get back from GCDAsyncSocket.

```
{
address = "127.0.0.1";
hostname = "127.0.0.1";
port = 52509;
socket = "<a0471600 01000000>"; }
```

Trying to figure out how to parse this into a mutable array or dictionary based on the address so I can display it in a tableview. This is coming from GCDAsyncSocket

Comment: What's the type of this object? Is it a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where is problem. if i would like to store this data I created a class which has parameters `address, hostname, port and socket` as NSString objects. And next insert this object class to NSMutableArray.

Comment: I don't know if data coming from GCDAsyncSocket is NSDictionary or something because i don't know about it, but i would to make this: http://pastebin.com/AvubLbE6

Comment: if data which coming to you is NSDictionary you must get it's element by use `dictionary objectForKey:@"address"` etc.

Comment: I follow that but how do I extract the values from a NSString that comes in like the above post into that array

Comment: you can use `rangeOfString` and `substractFromString: inRange` or something like that and substract all between " ". but for me this output is NSDictionary with multiple strings

Comment: My bad. the output is an NSDictionary. How can I work with it then?

Comment: i wrote it above. `string = [dictionary objectForKey:@"key"];`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16054/discussion-between-blindingdawn-and-tomasz-szulc)